# Listening to click events doesn't work in winjs

Tags: winjs

I'm trying to add some click listeners to some custom divs and the problem might be that I use navigation and the elements keep being deleted/added .

I need a dynamic way to add event listeners to objects , I kept searching but I couldn't find anything good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code on another question:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.id == "main_description"){

    }
});
```